# PHP Script - How to use php artisan command in my script?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'd like to create a php script which connects to a mysql server, makes changes on a database and runs a php artisan command.

The first part I have figured out (mysql connection) but is it possible to just put (for example):

`php artisan snipeit:ldap-sync --location_id=1`

into my script and it will run the command, or am I missing something here?

**I'd appreciate it if you could send me into the right direction wtih this. Thank you.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Artisan::call()`.

```
Artisan:call('snipeit:ldap-sync', [
    '--location_id' => 1
]);
```

It can also take a second parameter to specify an array of command parameters.

For more information, see [Programmatically Executing Commands.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands)

Answer (score 1):

You can call artisan command from code like this:

```
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```

Comment: So probably like this: Artisan:call('snipeit:ldap-sync --location_id=1'); ? Thank you!